# remove previous link triggered by js

Tags: javascript

I wrote the code below, to change the font, however, I'm still seeing old fonts in the console:

```
let font = document.getElementById("font");
if (font) {
  font.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let font = this.value;
    let link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = `assets/css/fonts/${font}.css`;
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    console.log(font);
  });
} else {
  let link = document.querySelector("link[href*='assets/css/fonts/']");
  if (link) {
    link.remove();
  }
}
```

**The HTML code**

```
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="font" name="font">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**Console:**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

my 2 questions:

- 1- How to remove the previous font when choosing a new one
- 2- How to save the font into local storage (until the user changes another font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be unnecessary to remove the link and create a new one on every selection, you can just reuse the first created link and then only change its `href`, like this:

```js
const font = document.getElementById("font");
const setFont = (link, font) => {
  link.href = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${font}`;
}
if (font) {
  const link = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("link"));
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  // setFont(link, localStorage.getItem('font-family') ?? 'Sans');
  font.addEventListener("change", function () {
    setFont(link, this.value);
    // localStorage.setItem('font-family', this.value);
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  font-family: Oswald, Silkscreen, Peralta, sans;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="font" name="font">
  <option value="Sans">Sans</option>
  <option value="Peralta">Peralta</option>
  <option value="Silkscreen">Silkscreen</option>
  <option value="Oswald">Oswald</option>
</select>
<div>Example</div>
```

Also, the selection value can be saved and retrieved from `localStorage` as in the comments, it is commented because the `localStorage` is not available in the sandbox here.